# Why did Chancellor Merkel invite just five European leaders to Berlin at "Obama's final day in Berlin"?

Tags: european-union, germany, barack-obama, angela-merkel

Chancellor Merkel held talks with US and European leaders in Berlin.
Anyway, from a politico-economic union of 28 member states, just the representatives of 5 were invited.  Did her office give an explanation of why she invited just five European leaders to Berlin at "Obama's final day in Berlin"?

http://www.dw.com/en/european-leaders-talk-trump-during-obamas-final-day-in-berlin/a-36433427

Comment: Nice analysis:
https://www.osw.waw.pl/en/publikacje/analyses/2016-11-23/germany-trumps-future-policies-fear-anti-globalisation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The five countries invited to meet the leaving American president were Germany (the host), France, the UK, Italy, Spain, in addition of course to the US. Those five countries are the five most populated countries in the EU, and also the five with the highest GDP.

It is clear that the aim of this meeting was to allow for an intimate and apical discussion. Inviting people from 28 countries would not have done the job.

If a sixth country had been invited, the natural choice would have been Poland. Poland is the sixth European Country in terms of population, it has a larger area than Italy and the UK, and would also be the sixth country by GDP if we use a PPP comparison (though it has a lower GDP than the much smaller Netherlands and Belgium at the current exchange rate). But the current administration of Poland has very cool relations with the rest of the EU,
especially with Merkel. So it was natural to stop at 5 guests.

Comment: Nice. It is worth noting that a) those were *bilateral* talks (i.e. they did not affect the EU as a whole) and, most important, that Obama is in his "lame duck" period so actual decisions are not to be expected of these talks.

Comment: Kind of doubtful Poland would have been invited given the animosity Obama has generated there.  He's extremely disliked by the Poles.

Comment: @KDog - According to Pew research, his positive ratings have always been above 50% in Poland, resting at 58% right now.  While lagging behind  the higher percentages in the nations invited to this meeting, that's hardly "disliked," or "animosity."

Comment: @PoloHoleSet You might want to give this a read http://harvardpolitics.com/online/hprgument-blog/poland-disillusion-trumps-obamas-popularity/

Comment: @KDog - Did YOU read that article?  It said that Obama had a 53% approval rating.  It also said that Bush had a higher approval rating than he did on other countries, but that was also still less than Obama.  Nothing in that article contradicted anything I said in my post.  Yes, Poland approves of Obama about 20 points less than other countries do, but 53% is still a decent level (Trump was polling around 9% in most countries recently), just not the immensely high approval Obama has most other places, contrary to conservative claims about the US losing prestige under this president.

Comment: @poloholeset the article called Obama both a hypocrite and a legendary ass. That's both animosity and dislike

Comment: @KDog - Yeah, and if I write an article calling Queen Elizabeth a reptilian alien, but don't have any facts to back it up, does the fact that an author made that characterization make it true?  What we see is that Obama is wildly unpopular with the person who wrote the article, and LESS popular in Poland than in other European nations, but still generally popular or approved of by the majority of the Polish population, contrary to your claims.  You are claiming he's hated by the Polish people, as a group.  That article shows the opposite to be true when they do refer to available facts.